# Visual Code C++ "No such file or directory" message when trying to compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I just started to get into coding. I eventually got `JavaScript` code to start working in Visual Studio Code, but I am having significant trouble with `C++`.

The error message:

[image: Error message and code]

My `tasks.json` file:

[image: tasks.json]

My `launch.json` file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz31I.jpg

Could any explain to me, someone who's relatively new to this, how I can get this to properly work?

Answer (score 0):

The file name for your `c++` source appears to be "test.cpp," but your compilation command line is looking for the file, "Testing.cpp":

```
g++ -g Testing.cpp
```

Try changing this to:

```
g++ -g test.cpp
```

Comment: @FrazerZero Then *maybe* you need to give `g++` the full path to your source file(s).

Comment: How would I go about doing that? And by source files do you mean the files where I save all my C++ programs?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again, but just in case you missed my comment; I really need the help and this is pretty much my only serious hurdle towards free experimentation.

Comment: @FrazerZero It appears that you're on a Mac, so I can't be completely sure, but you maybe need something like: `g++ -g C:/Users/Project/Folder/test.cpp` (or maybe even add `"` quotes around the file-path).

Comment: An error still pops up(Both with and without quotes): https://imgur.com/a/ofX9Q1j  |||  I tried following an online tutorial and this is what my launch.json looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/LtKufVq

Comment: @FrazerZero I have been travelling for the past few days - I'll take another look, and give some more thoughts, later today.

Comment: Nevermind/Don't worry. I switched to Microsoft Visual Studio(2019), it runs my code just fine now.